# How to correct this for loop over tuple function in Python?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

Here is a program where each line was split into pairs using tuples, such that every alphabet had a corresponding numeric as A:6, B:6, C:35 ..etc If a value for less than 10, then the alphabets were converted to N. The following is the code. I find that my code does not loop over the tuple function in the last part of the code. It takes in only a single sequence and does not loop over the other

```
tutorial = open('c:/test/z.txt','r')
## Input file looks like
>qrst
ABCDE--  6  6 35 25 10
>qqqq
ABBDE--  7  7 28 29  2

org = []
seqlist = []
seqstring = ""
for line in tutorial:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        if seqstring!= "":
            seqlist.append(seqstring)
            seqstring = ""
        org.append(line.rstrip("\n"))
    else:
        seqstring += line.rstrip("\n")
seqlist.append(seqstring)
l = seqlist
#print l

j = []
ll = len(seqlist)
for i in range(0,ll):
    sq = l[i]
    sequence = sq.split(" ")[0] ## Stores only the alphabets
    qualities = sq.split(" ")[1:] ## Stores only the numeric
    qualities = filter(None, qualities)
    for sub in sequence:
        if sub == "-": ## If sequences have "-", it inserts a "0" in that position in corresponding number
            idx = list(sequence).index(sub)
            qualities.insert(idx,"0")

# Error in the steps below
pairs = []
for sub in l:
    print sub
    new_list = []
    for x in range(len(sequence)):
        print x
        new_tuple = (sequence[x], qualities[x]) #Printing this step, notice that only one of the sequences is printed twice. ERROR
        print new_tuple
        if int(qualities[x]) < 10:
            new_tuple = ("Z",   qualities[x]) 
        new_list.append(new_tuple)
    pairs.append(new_list)
print pairs
# When I print pairs it looks like this: [[('Z', '7'), ('Z', '7'), ('B', '28'), ('D', '29'), ('Z', '2'), ('Z', '0'), ('Z', '0')], [('Z', '7'), ('Z', '7'), ('B', '28'), ('D', '29'), ('Z', '2'), ('Z', '0'), ('Z', '0')]]
# Sequence#2 is printed twice over. The first one is not taken in
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd I have attached the precise problem at the end of the code, now

Comment: `for x in range(len(sequences):` should be `for x in range(len(sequences)):`. But wait, what is `sequences`?

Comment: That was a typo. It is just sequence. Sequence is a supposed to be a list with ['ABCDE--','ABBDE--']. But I am not sure if it is printing as a list or not

Comment: @biogeek, but if you set to Z when q < 10 then you get two (Z, 7)s. isn't this already expected? (those are for `('A', '7') ('B', '7')`)

Comment: There are 2 sublists in sequence : ['ABCDE--','ABBDE--']. Look at the output in the last line of code. It prints modified version of (ABBDE--) --> (ZZBDZZZ) TWICE. Only the second element of sequence is read.

Comment: Your two list `sequence` and `qualities` only take the last element of `seqlist` because in each step of loop, you assign them to `sq[i].split(" ")[0]` and `sq[i].split(" ")[1]`. I think you should use `append`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_inputs = []  # <---- add this
for i in range(0,ll):
    sq = l[i]
    sequence = sq.split(" ")[0] ## Stores only the alphabets
    qualities = sq.split(" ")[1:] ## Stores only the numeric
    qualities = filter(None, qualities)
    for sub in sequence:
        if sub == "-":
            idx = list(sequence).index(sub)
            qualities.insert(idx,"0")
    # also add this ***********************
    all_inputs.append((sequence, qualities))

pairs = []
# change this *******************************
for sequence, qualities in all_inputs:
    print sub 
    new_list = []
    for x in range(len(sequence)):
        print x
        new_tuple = (sequence[x], qualities[x]) 
        print new_tuple
        if int(qualities[x]) < 10: 
            new_tuple = ("Z",   qualities[x]) 
        new_list.append(new_tuple)
    pairs.append(new_list)
print pairs
```

gives:

```
[[('Z', '6'), ('Z', '6'), ('C', '35'), ('D', '25'), ('E', '10'), ('Z', '0'), ('Z', '0')], [('Z', '7'), ('Z', '7'), ('B
', '28'), ('D', '29'), ('Z', '2'), ('Z', '0'), ('Z', '0')]]
```

Comment: I had a follow up question. If I had a input sequence `>qrst A10` `>qqqq A2` How can I still use the same code to split the alpha numeric? Can I accommodate both `['A 10','A 2']` and `['A10','A2']` types of input file in the same line of code?