# How to modify .split function to to apply to different alpha numeric inputs?

Tags: python, split, alphanumeric

I have the following two types of input:

```
## Case 1 (a)
# Input #1(a)
>qrst
ABC 10 9 7
>qqqq
ACC 2 5 3

# Case 1 (b) --> Simplified form of Case 1(a)
# Input #1()
>qrst
A 10
>qqqq
A 2

# After reading in the file and making it a list I store the above in l
l = ['ABC 10 9 7', 'ACC 2 5 3'] # Case 1(a)
l = ['A 10', 'A 2'] # Case 1(b)

 #In the following code I split the alpha-numeric elements above and
 #create separate lists where I store the alphabets alone (in list "sequences") and 
 #numeric alone (in list "qualities")

ll = len(l)
all_inputs = [] 
for i in range(0,ll):
    sq = l[i]
    sequence = sq.split(" ")[0] ## Stores only the alphabets
    qualities = sq.split(" ")[1:] ## Stores only the numeric
    qualities = filter(None, qualities)
    for sub in sequence:
        if sub == "-":
            idx = list(sequence).index(sub)
            qualities.insert(idx,"0")  
    all_inputs.append((sequence, qualities))
    print 

   #Case1(a) Output reads currently reads as
   A   #print sequence
   ['2']  #print qualities
```

I encounter another type of input file as follows:

```
## Case 2
 #  Input #2
 >qrst
A    #No space after A

10
>qqqq
A    #No space after A

2

Here 
l = ['A10', 'A2']

I use the same code as above

#Case2 Output reads currently reads as
A2 #print sequences
[] #print qualities
```

I need #Case 2 to also have the output
    A   #print sequence
    ['2']  #print qualities

How do I modify the code above such that it can accommodate both ['ABC 10 9 7', 'ACC 2 5 3'] or ['A 10','A 2'] or['A10','A2'] types of input file/ 'l'?
I need Case 2 to have the same output as Case 1(b), so that I can apply the same line of code later on. But remember, it has to be a generalized code for Case 1 and Case 2.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for homework help. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: Also, your question is not well posed.

Comment: Please revise your question to be more clear with how each of your sample inputs should behave with an exact expected output. Please read how to put together a [mcve] to help with editing your question so it is well recieved.

Comment: I have already done the 'hard' part of the coding..and it works. I genuinely do not understand how I can write a more generalizable code, which I think is a reasonable doubt to ask. Also, I am working on a research project, so I need to make sure that all types of inputs are readable. If you can let me know what part of the question is unclear, I can modify accordingly

Comment: @idjaw I have edited. Hope its clear now

Comment: If you are actually working with some standard bioinformatics file format, telling us which one it is would allow us to google a proper spec where your examples are vague or incomplete. This looks like some adaptation of FASTA format?

Answer (score 0):

A regex would be a good approach for this, you're looking for a letter `([A-Z])` followed by an optional space `?` followed by one or more digits `(\d+)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('([A-Z]) ?(\d+)', 'A10').groups()
('A', '10')
>>> re.match('([A-Z]) ?(\d+)', 'A 10').groups()
('A', '10')
```

Comment: But how do I do this for a large sequence? What is I had l = ['A10', 'A2','C8','D20']? and I need to split all of them

Comment: like in your code, use a loop and apply it to each element

Comment: I am unfamiliar with re.match. So if I have `l = ['A10', 'A2','C8','D20']` does my next line read `for i in l:` `re.match('([A-Z]) ?(\d+)', 'i''i+1').groups()` . What type of inputs does it take in?

Comment: I think it should just be `for i in l: re.match('([A-Z]) ?(\d+)', i).groups()`

Comment: No, I think you are mixing up where I want the difference in code First, the code you are suggesting is printing `[('A', '10'), ('A', '2')]`, I need `['A 10', 'A 2'] as l.  OR Else I need the difference to be reflected in the output. At the end of the last two lines of code, I print `sequences` and `qualities`. I need the output for all cases to be the same. i.e. if the initial input was ['A 10', 'T 8'] or ['AGT 10 10 20', 'TAT 2 3 4'] or if it was as described in Case 2 (Only single alphabets).

Answer (score 0):

would this work:

```
import re

input_seq = "A10 B   20 C30 D1 Z   67"
input_raw = re.split(r'([A-Z]) *(\d+)' , input_seq)
input_clean = [x for x in input_raw if x and not x.isspace()]
print zip(input_clean[::2], input_clean[1::2])
```

*gives*:

```
[('A', '10'), ('B', '20'), ('C', '30'), ('D', '1'), ('Z', '67')]
```

if you change the last expression:

```
print [ "{} {}".format(*x) for x in zip(input_clean[::2], input_clean[1::2]) ]
```

you get:

```
['A 10', 'B 20', 'C 30', 'D 1', 'Z 67']
```

alternatively, you can try normalizing the input:

```
input_seq = "A10 B   20 C30 D1 Z   67"
print re.sub(r'([A-Z]) *(\d+)', r'\1 \2', input_seq)
```

this will print:

```
A 10 B 20 C 30 D 1 Z 67
```

if you only want to modify the list of inputs:

```
l = ['A10', 'A2']
l = [ re.sub(r'([A-Z]) *(\d+)', r'\1 \2', x) for x in l]
print l
```

this prints:

```
['A 10', 'A 2']
```

Comment: I have modified the question. Look at Case 1(a) and Case 1(b). Case 1(b) and 2, are 'special cases' of Case 1

Comment: provide case 1(a) example for case 2, is it "ABC2 3 3"?

Comment: Okay, just consider 3 cases. Case A `l = ['ABC- 10 9 7 2', 'ACC- 2 5 3 0']`, Case B `l = ['A 10', 'A 3']`, Case C `l =['A10', 'A3']`. The "alphabets" can have "alphabets and characters like "-" or "?"

Comment: then I think the answer should already help you, where are you stuck?

Comment: I use `l = ['ATGC 10 9 8 7 ', 'AGGG 2 7 8 6']` `input_seq = l`
`input_raw = re.split(r'([A-Z]) *(\d+)' , input_seq)`
`input_clean = [x for x in input_raw if x and not x.isspace()]`
`print [ "{} {}".format(*x) for x in zip(input_clean[::2], input_clean[1::2]) ]`  I get this error message:  File "C:\Users\...."  line 27, in <module>
    input_raw = re.split(r'([A-Z]) *(\d+)' , input_seq)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 171, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: the `input_seq` is the variable that stores the line `AGGG 2 7 8 6`, you'll create `l` after these normalizations. so first read the line, process it and then proceed to create the `l`

Comment: We have discussed a part of this question before. Perhaps you can recollect it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462393/how-to-correct-this-for-loop-over-tuple-function-in-python?noredirect=1#comment66246528_39462393). I just need to modify this code to make sure that Case 2, is included.

Comment: If `l = ['ATGC 10 9 8 7 ', 'AGGG 2 7 8 6']` I don't have to process it. I can use the original code. I only tun into trouble when I have Case 2. So I'm trying to understand how I can generalise the code such that, no matter what the input Case 1(a), 1(b) or 2..I will have comparable output

Comment: @perral : Can I change `([A-Z]) *(\d+)` to include "-" and "?"

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly now. I will be sure to read and study more of the re.sub command